# How can I create a Jenkins plugin without referring to parent POM?

Tags: java, maven, plugins, jenkins, parent-pom

According to the Jenkins plugin tutorial the plugin's POM refers to the Plugin Parent POM:

```
<parent>
    <groupId>org.jenkins-ci.plugins</groupId>
    <artifactId>plugin</artifactId>
    <version>2.2</version>
</parent>
```

I am creating a Jenkins plugin for internal use in my company. And all Maven projects in the company MUST refer to one POM. Therefore I can't refer my plugin to both.

Is there a way to create a Jenknis plugin with POM not referring to Plugin Parent POM?

Comment: In my honest opinion, here what jenkins web site say: 
Maven uses it for building your plugin. All Jenkins plugins should be based on the Plugin Parent POM. It says should and not "must" Open that pom.xml and verify all properties and dependencies in it. You may add them to another pom. And it should work without any problem

Comment: Well, creating the intermediate POM which is a copy of Jenkins Plugin Parent POM worked.

Comment: Added my comment as an answer if someone stumble with the same problem

Answer (score 1):

I recently had the same question. The minimal configuration I found in order to avoid inheriting from Jenkins' parent POM:

```
<dependencies>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.jenkins-ci.main</groupId>
        <artifactId>jenkins-core</artifactId>
        <version>1.580.1</version>
        <scope>provided</scope>
    </dependency>
</dependencies>

<build>
    <plugins>
        <plugin>
            <groupId>org.jenkins-ci.tools</groupId>
            <artifactId>maven-hpi-plugin</artifactId>
            <extensions>true</extensions>
        </plugin>
    </plugins>
</build>
```

You can of course change the version. The important part is the `<extensions>true</extensions>`, otherwise the hpi packaging won't be recognized by Maven.

Answer (score 0):

In my honest opinion, here what jenkins web site say: Maven uses it for building your plugin. All Jenkins plugins should be based on the Plugin Parent POM. It says should and not "must" Open that pom.xml and verify all properties and dependencies in it. You may add them to another pom. And it should work without any problem